# How to validate a currency input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form, and that includes salary, I need to check if the input value for salary is a valid currency and has two decimal places because that is what the database accepts. If the input for salary has alphabets (a-z) or symbols (!@#%^&*() except for the $ or other currency sign) it should change the border color.

example:

```
  10000.00
  25846.00
  213464.12
```

code:

```
function isNumeric(){
   var numeric = document.getElementById("txtSalary").value;
   var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
   if (regex.test(numeric)){
     $("#txtSalary").css("border-color","#FFFFFF");
   }else{
      $("#txtSalary").css("border-color","#FF0000");
   }
 }
```

This is already working as I wanted too, but the problem is I got 6 more input boxes that needs this kind of validation. How can I make that function, when called change the border-color of the specific selector and will return false is the value is not numeric something like:

```
isNumeric(selector);

function isNumeric(selector){
    var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
     $(selector).filter(function() {
        return (regex.test(this.value));
     }).css("border-color","#FF0000");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You already have a function. Just let it accept parameters.

Comment: that should be 'numeric'.

Comment: replace document.getElementById("txtSalary") to document.getElementById("txtSalary").value

Comment: Unless you are keen to learn everything from scratch (which is often a good thing), you may find your time is better spent investigating a JavaScript validation framework such as unobtrusive instead of writing you own.

Answer (score 4):

try to use html5 pattern directly on your input:

```
<input type='text' pattern='^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$'/>
```

it works with all modern browsers.
it will make the border red if the pattern is false

Comment: this not supported in old browsers

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work for me and also i to return false if the value is not numeric.

Comment: that's what i've written, only modern browsers.
or add html5shiv to make it work with any browser

Answer (score 2):

I needed something that would allow for US-formatted entries that could include a `,` thousands separator and optional 2-digit decimal places. I came up with this:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Works as advertised. Add support for `0` and `0.00` by changing `[1-9]` to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumeric(id, border){
   var numeric = document.getElementById(id);
   var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
   if (regex.test(numeric)){
     $('#'+border).css("border-color","#FFFFFF");
   }else{
      $('#'+border).css("border-color","#FF0000");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Or have isNumeric take a DOM object. `var elem = document.getElementById('foo'); isNumeric(elem);`

Comment: but how to change the border-color of its corresponding textbox?

Comment: I'm assuming that `#txtEmail` is just an example ID in your original code, so presumably the field represented by the function parameter `id` is the one that should have its border manipulated when validating (i.e. don't tweak the borders in `#txtEmail` each time, tweak those of `id`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery/JavaScript, then you can just pass your selector like this:

```
function isNumeric(sel){
  var $numeric = $(sel);
  var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
  if (regex.test($numeric.val())){
    $numeric.css("border-color","#FFFFFF");
      } else {
    $numeric.css("border-color","#FF0000");
  }
}
```

You could also take advantage of the `HTMLInputElement`'s built-in validation (in the candidate recommendation for HTML 5):

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$">
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

For styling, you can then use the [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3avalid) and [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid) pseudo-selectors.

If you need to guarantee cross-browser compatibility, you could use a polyfill like [this](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping to use a css selector instead of Ids, I'd recommend jQuery for cross-browser support, but nevertheless in js you can do:

```
function isNumeric(selector){
   var elements = document.querySelector(selector);

   var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
   for (var i=0, i < elements.length; i++) {

       // i added a test on the value attribute, 
       // as your original doesn't look like it should work

       if (regex.test(elements[i].getAttribute('value'))){
          $(elements[i]).css("border-color","#FFFFFF");
       }
       else{
          $(elements[i]).css("border-color","#FF0000");
       }
   }
}
```

or a version using jQuery for the selectors:

```
function isNumeric(selector){
   var elements = $(selector);

   var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
   elements.each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);

       // i added a test on the value attribute, 
       // as your original doesn't look like it should work

       if (regex.test($this.val())){
          $this.css("border-color","#FFFFFF");
       }
       else{
          $this.css("border-color","#FF0000");
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: I need to also change the border of that value not just the txtEmail.

Comment: I've fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery, so utilize it. Instead of adding the event in HTML markup, add it in jquery. like this:

```
$('#textOne,#textTwo,#textThree').on('eventNameHere', isNumeric);
```

and a small change in your function:

```
function isNumeric(){
   var numeric = this.value;
   -------
}
```

**UPDATED**:

(*If you are **not** using textbox events but a button event which needs to handle all the textbox validations*):

```
$('#textOne,#textTwo,#textThree').each(isNumeric);
```

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: @QKWS I will(depends). Are you calling your function on any event?

Comment: Yes. On click button Next.

Comment: @QKWS Check my updated post. mention your textbox id's in place of `#textOne`, `#textTwo`.....

Answer (score 0):

```
function onlyPrice(e) {
    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if( unicode != 8 )
    {
        if(unicode < 9 || unicode > 9 && unicode < 46 || unicode > 57 || unicode == 47) {
            if(unicode == 37 || unicode == 38) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="price" onkeypress="return onlyPrice(event)" />
```

Comment: Try this i am using this script in my project for price validation.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AssignNumeric() {
        $('.numeric').each(function (i) {
            $(this).blur(function () {
                var regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
                if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FFFFFF");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        AssignNumeric();
    });
</script>
```

**html:**

```
    <input id="Text1" type="text" class="numeric" />
    <input id="Text2" type="text" class="numeric" />
    <input id="Text3" type="text" class="numeric" />
    <input id="Text4" type="text" class="numeric" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:
`<input type='text' pattern='^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})$'/>`

It forces you to have at least one number after the dot, so you wont get anything like:

```
10000.
25846
```

It will only accept:

```
10000.1
25846.30
213464.12
```

Of course you need more server side validations in the case someone wants to bypass this one by changing the tag or javascript in the browser.

Comment: Your preferred solution is missing :)

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that! >,<