# Currency field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are from and to currency fields which allows only positive integers not decimals and maximum amount should not exceed 1 billion. And it needs to be comma seperated values on blur or keyup events. For this, I tried with masked edit extender in ajax control tool kit but comma's are placed inside the textbox on initial load.

I am now trying with regular expression validator with `^\d+(,\d+)*$`  to check for comma seperated integer and custom validator to check if the amount is greater than 1 billion and key up event to format it to comma seperated. Issue with this approach is it is sometimes allowing multiple comma's such as 8,,000 and validations are passing. User needs to again go and click on the textbox and on blur it is reformatted to 8000.

I was wondering if there is any other way that I am missing to achieve this kind of functionality.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with using `regular expression` !!! Or you may use [Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204390/how-to-validate-a-currency-input) solution

Comment: @sunny I don't see anything wrong with your regex and it should not let 8,,000 pass through. Can you provide the full validation code that you have to see if there is another issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression

> ^\d+[,]?(\d+)*$

The comma is optional like in your regular expression, however the ? mark means there is etheir no comma or one, while * mark means there is etheir no comma, one or many.

**EDIT**

This regular expression will accept multiple commas as long as they are not following another comma.

> ^\d+([,]?\d+)*$

Comment: Your regex does not work with correct multiple commas 8,000,000.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the comment. I will edit my post regarding that problem.

Comment: Your edit is also incorrect as it will allow something like 8,0,0,0 to pass through... which is the same like his original regex. His regex will actually block 8,,000, which is what he complained about, so the issue is not his regex.